# icedtea-7-plugin non-functional in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: firefox, 13.04, java, icedtea

I installed(sudo apt-get install) icedtea-7-plugin (and all its dependencies) and have closed firefox and reopened it; and the plugin still does not appear in http//about:plugins

Is there a fix for this?
Output of: java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Output of: update-java-alternatives -l

```
java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-gcj-4.7 /usr/lib/jvm/java-gcj-4.7
```

Comment: got it working. it's just strange. Maybe it was because of the upgrade to 13.04. SOmething might have been left out of the upgrade. Who knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by purging the icetea7 and jdk, and reinstalling them. It will tell you that you need to install icetea 6 and openjdk6 when you try to purge the files, do it. Then reinstall the icedtea 7 plugin and dependencias, and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: java wasn't working after upgrade to 13.04, icedtea7 was installed, but Firefox didn't detect it. Purging icedtea7 and openjdk7 did not resolve it for me.  I can tell you what I did to solve it, but I don't know which steps are essential:

I tried Frank's solution, but it didn't work for me.  As he notes, purging icedtea7 and jdk will require require installing openjdk6.  If you run

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-6-jre openjdk-7-jre
```

it will require installing `default-jre-headless`.  I purged all three at the same time:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-6-jre openjdk-7-jre default-jre-headless
```

I then ran

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then I reinstalled openjdk7, and several packages that were suggested during that installation: `default-jre`, `equivs`, and `icedtea-7-plugin`:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

After that, I closed and reopened Firefox, and java works fine.

Comment: This worked for me. The URL http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp is what I used to validate that it was working.  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question and after reading others responses could make it by adding the plugin package

```
apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```