# Unable to run Java, IcedTea on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: 12.04, installation, java, openjdk

I have updated to 12.04 LTS from 10.04 LTS because I could not get java to test as working on http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

... I still can't get java working.

- I have installed icedtea and the openjdk through the software center.
- I have run 'apt-get update; apt-get upgrade'.
- I have tried Chrome and Firefox.
- I have read all over the Internet and this problem keeps coming up.  For example: [icedtea-7-plugin non-functional in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289745/)  I have followed the instructions there and elsewhere and java still fails to validate and run for me and, apparently, a lot of people.

I am out of ideas and java still does not validate and run for me.

Any help would most definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this test seems not to work for me either. I get a screen like this:

[image: Screenshot: We are unable to verify if Java is currently installed and enabled in your browser]

but all other Java web applications are working fine. So maybe the test is broken, not the IcedTea. Try this test instead: [Java Tester](http://www.javatester.org/version.html).

Comment: I started this journey on 10.04 LTS and both javatester.org (your link) and the oracle java test (my link at top) did not work.  I read around and there seems to have been some trouble with Java on 10.04 LTS so I upgraded to 12.04 LTS.  Now my UI is laggy and I have to relearn where everything is (command-s anyone?) but installing icedtea and disabling all my browser security allows your java test link to work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on the **Easy Linux Tips Project** [Installing Java In Ubuntu](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java)

Comment: The link you provided is FANTASTIC.  It drills right down and tells you ever step (more than I need actually).  But when stuck this link has the goods even if one is having brain failure.  I just don't have enough reputation to upvote you.  And, sadly, the other answer is the one that showed me that I was actually installed correctly but the Oracle Java test is broken so I have to check that one as the answer for the special case I was seeing with 12.04 LTS.  Thank you!